# How can i get the text box value on click button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a 8 set of forms like given below.all class names are same and form names are same. but the input what i will be providing will be different on all the forms. i need to get the input value from text box when i click on the filter button.How can i do this in jquery using `$(this).`?
here is what i have tried.

```
$(".filterit").click(function(){
  $(this).$('myform').$('filter1').val();
});
```

html

```
    <form name="myform" method="post">
        <table class="pop-table">
        <tr><td><input type="text" value="" name="filter1" class="filter-1"><td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="text" value="" name="filter2" class="filter-2"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><button class="btn btn-warning filterit">FILTER</button></td></tr></table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.closest()` for traversed to the closest element and `.find()` to search the element class or id or selector and `.val()` for getting input value

```
$(".filterit").click(function(){
   $(this).closest('table').find('.filter-1').val(); // for first text box
   $(this).closest('table').find('.filter-2').val(); // for second
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dxuztgpL/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1) traverse to closest table element

2) and the find element with selector `.filter-1` in it

```
$(".filterit").click(function () {
   var inp1val = $(this).closest('table').find('.filter-1').val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#filter_btn").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().find("#filter2").val();
});
```

```html
<form name="myform" method="post">
  <table class="pop-table">
    <tr><td><input type="text" value="" id="filter1" name="filter1" class="filter-1"><td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="text" value="" id="filter2" name="filter2" class="filter-2"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button id="filter_btn" class="btn btn-warning filterit">FILTER</button></td></tr></table>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make the button type="submit"

Then your event should be

```
$(".filterit").submit(function(){
    //this keyword is now the form that was submitted
});
```

Hope this helps!